# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo, transactions

I'm trying to set up an "insert topics/posts" page for a forum I am creating, but when I run any inputs through it, it gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''test' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\FORUM\create_topic.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\FORUM\create_topic.php(29): PDO->exec('INSERT INTO top...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\FORUM\create_topic.php on line 29

the code is in an else statement and looks like this:

```
} else {
// Start a transaction with the database
$DB_con->beginTransaction();
$query = $DB_con->exec("INSERT INTO topics (topic_subject, topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by) VALUES('" . $_POST['topic_subject']) . ", " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ")";

if (!$query) {
    echo 'An error occured whilst creating your topic. Please try again.';
    $DB_con->rollback();
} else {
    $topicid = $DB_con->lastInsertId();
    $query = $DB_con->exec("INSERT INTO posts(post_content, post_date, post_topic, post_by) VALUES('" . $_POST['post_content']) . "', NOW(), " . $topicid . ", " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ")";

    if (!$query) {
        echo "There was a problem inserting your post. Try again later.";
        $DB_con->rollback();
    } else {
        $DB_con->commit();
        echo 'You have successfully created <a href="topic.php?id='. $topicid . '">your new topic</a>.';
    }
}
```

I thought the issue could have been that I was using a reserved SQL command in my code, but I cannot uncover it. I'm trying to use transactions for the first time and the whole concept is throwing me off.
If this is a bad question - Let me know and I'll take it of, update or rephrase it! Thanks :)

Comment: sounds like an sql injection here with the apostrophe

Comment: oh wait; you're using 4 columns in the first query but only 2 values, that's why it failed.

Comment: Your first query has a never closing  `'`  after `VALUES(` That's why its showing syntax error.

Comment: @Riya ah yes, that too. Their code failed based on both our comments. Nice catch.